# HTML5: working with the camera: sizing issue

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

I'm writing this HTML5 camera demo and I want to capture the video on a click of a button.
The thing is, I want to save the image with the original size of the video or any other "big" size. But, I also want to present the image to the user with a small version of the image.

How to do that?

I use those HTML tags:

```
<video width="500" style="margin:0 auto; border:1px;" height="auto" autoplay></video>
<canvas width="auto" height="auto" style="display:none;"></canvas>
```

Comment: How to do that? Pretty simple. You just need to write the right code.
I use this language: `JavaScript`

Comment: What have you already tried? At which point do you fail? What exactly do you expect from the community? Your provided HTML-Tags are very useless for us ... Did you already searched for this on google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/Taking_webcam_photos)</kbd>

#### The HTML markup

```
<video id="video"></video>
<button id="startbutton">Take photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/320/261" id="photo" alt="photo">
```

#### The full script

```
(function() {

  var streaming = false,
      video        = document.querySelector('#video'),
      canvas       = document.querySelector('#canvas'),
      photo        = document.querySelector('#photo'),
      startbutton  = document.querySelector('#startbutton'),
      width = 320,
      height = 0;

  navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia);

  navigator.getMedia(
    {
      video: true,
      audio: false
    },
    function(stream) {
      if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
        video.mozSrcObject = stream;
      } else {
        var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
      }
      video.play();
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log("An error occured! " + err);
    }
  );

  video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev){
    if (!streaming) {
      height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth/width);
      video.setAttribute('width', width);
      video.setAttribute('height', height);
      canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
      streaming = true;
    }
  }, false);

  function takepicture() {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    photo.setAttribute('src', data);
  }

  startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
      takepicture();
    ev.preventDefault();
  }, false);

})();
```

Comment: By the way, it isn't working. I'm debugging it now tough

Comment: Why does data equals to "Data;"?

Comment: Here you got the [detailled explenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/Taking_webcam_photos#The_bit_by_bit_explanation) of the given source code. Maybe you consider providing us a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can help you better.

Comment: I ran the jsfiddle example, and it doesn't work on my up to date Firefox (27.0.1). The camera operate, but I can't take a picture. It does work on Chrome.